# error 'L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'' in Optim function

Tags: r, model-fitting

I have a function for fitting Rescorla - Wagner model on data

```
fit.block = function(par, df,Nalt){ 
  Q      = rep(0,Nalt)
  trials = dim(df)[1]
  action = df$action
  reward = df$reward
  pAction= rep(NA, trials)
  alpha  =par[1]
  beta   =par[2]
  
  for (t in 1:trials){
    pAction[t]   = exp(beta*Q[action[t]]) / sum(exp(beta*Q))
    Q[action[t]] = Q[action[t]] + alpha*(reward[t] - Q[action[t]])
  }
  return (-sum(log(pAction)))
}
```

and I try to use Optim in order to get 2 parameters from the fitting :

````
 N <-12
rec.parms<- lapply(1:N, function(s) {if (s%%10==T) {print(paste(' subj=',s,sep=''))}
  
  optim(par= c(0.2,2),
        fn = fit.block, df= df_for_par %>% filter (s==subject),Nalt=2,
        lower=c(0,1), upper=c(1,8), method="L-BFGS-B")$par}) ```
````

data has 3 columns : `subject` (integer 1:12) , `action` (1/2) , `reward` (1/0)

I keep getting this error : `L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'`
i dont have NAs in my data or INF values.
What is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that the function evaluation does not result in INF for some parameters? For ex that division you have in pAction.

Comment: I generated some data according to your parameters in the question (10 obs per subject) and it worked without generating an error.  Can you post the data you're using or some example data that reproduce the error?